# Не отправляется почта с почтового сервера exim4

Tags: debian, email, smtp, exim4

Настроил на виртульном сервере Debian exim4+courier. Проблема с отправкой почты. Почта принимается но не хочет отправлять. Отправляет только на yandex.ru.

```
    This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  parliament888@gmail.com
    SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
    host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [173.194.222.26]:
    550-5.7.1 [95.213.199.29       1] Our system has detected an unusual rate of
    550-5.7.1 unsolicited mail originating from your IP address. To protect our
    550-5.7.1 users from spam, mail sent from your IP address has been blocked.
    550-5.7.1 Please visit
    550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126 to review our Bulk Email
    550 5.7.1 Senders Guidelines. ao8si4976767lbc.179 - gsmtp

------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------

Return-path: <studio@ils-team.ru>
Received: from [95.213.199.29] (helo=mail.ils-team.ru)
    by localhost with esmtpa (Exim 4.84)
    (envelope-from <studio@ils-team.ru>)
    id 1aeTOj-00082a-Hv
    for parliament888@gmail.com; Fri, 11 Mar 2016 23:10:57 +0300
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Fri, 11 Mar 2016 20:10:57 +0000
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--=_RainLoop_164_358454752.1457727057"
Message-ID: <96f147614e936bcfa6e6de3a01dbea77@mail.ils-team.ru>
X-Mailer: RainLoop/1.9.4.402
From: studio@ils-team.ru
Subject: test
To: parliament888@gmail.com


----=_RainLoop_164_358454752.1457727057
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

test

----=_RainLoop_164_358454752.1457727057
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"t=
ext/html; charset=3Dutf-8" /></head><body><div data-html-editor-font-wrap=
per=3D"true" style=3D"font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">t=
est</div></body></html>

----=_RainLoop_164_358454752.1457727057--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не до конца все [настроено](http://mxtoolbox.com/domain/mail.ils-team.ru/).

```
dmarc   ils-team.ru Missing or Invalid Record
spf ils-team.ru No records found
dns ils-team.ru SOA Expire Value out of recommended range
```

последние два - это предупреждения, а первый - ошибка.

Я что-то не совсем понял, у вас и MX записи нет? Если так, то вам, что бы на gmail да и многие другие что-то отправлять - еще настраивать и настраивать.

Comment: Не совсем понял что еще нужно настроить, можете по подробнее рассказать!?

Comment: @pwnz22, я думаю, лучше задать вопросы по ошибкам и предупреждениям **отдельно**. по одному вопросу на каждый вопрос (прошу прощения за тавтологию).

Comment: Почему вы решили что MX не настроены?

Comment: `mxtoolbox` пишет, что `No Records Exist`, хотя если немного времени прошло, то может не находить пока. З.Ы. я после недавней настройки всех записей и прочих антиспам пришел к тому, чтобы просто использовать серверы провайдера\гугля и т.п., больно геморный процесс этот стал.

Comment: Помогло добавление dmarс записи, спасибо большое

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста, сам просто недавно через эти семь кругов проходил )